# How to get classes that JVM calls in runtime?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a very big project on java and I want to know time and class that JVM calls for debugging purposes.

Comment: Would a profiler be what you are looking for?

Comment: Your question is to vague to receive a valuable answer

Comment: For your purpose, you can use log. There are many good libraries for logging in Java and you can use them to log in the console/file such as log4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Java VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) for profiling the application. See the instructions [here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/profiler.html).

Also other commercial and non-commercial profilers are available. See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) for more information.